# I am trying to create an individual document term matrix for each of the rows in my dataset. I have applied the following code to each

Tags: r

I am trying to establish a seperate document term matrix for each of the individual rows in a csv file. I have successfully read the csv file into R-Studio using the read.csv command. The first step to creating a document term matrix using the tm package, as far as I could figure out, would be to create an individual corpus for each of the rows of the file and to try and achieve this, I created the following code.

```
for(i in 1:no_row)
{
 data$TextCorpus[i]<-Corpus(VectorSource(data$Text[i]))

 #print(data$TextCorpus[i])
}
```

Where `no_row` equals the number of rows in the column (this was done using the command `no_row<-nrow(data))` the `data$TextCorpus` column is a column I created to store the corpus's created by the loop and `data$text` refers to the column the data being used to create the individual corpus's.

I expected that this would produce a corpus for each of the individual rows however, when I apply the `class()` function to the `data$Text_Corpus` column, it says that the column is classed as a list and this is preventing me from applying `tm_map` functions to individual rows of a column. Furthermore, when I apply the `as.Corpus` function or any similar function to the column, this has no effect and still the `data$TextCorpus` column is classified as a list. Does anybody know how to fix this problem? It is greatly appreciated.

P.S. If corpus's isn't the plural of corpus, please feel free to correct me in your response.

Comment: That octothorpe is going to prevent execution of the loop.

Comment: @42- the loop does execute without an error. Could you please expand on your comment?